# How to measure the current generated in permanent magnet dc motor/generaator?

Tags: motor, dc, generator

A motor of dia 1cm and 3 cm height and 200gms of weight.
will it be able to generate 6 amperes of current?

Can it handle that much amount of current?

If not then how can I measure the current generated by this permanent magnet motor when I have Voltage generated?

Also how to measure the resistance of the motor?
Will it be current to use ohms law to find the current generated?

Comment: Sounds lke you've blown the fuse in the current range, or you didn't move the red probe to the 10A socket.

Comment: I did move the red probe to 10 ampheres